# Installing OCaml bindings for LLVM

Tags: ocaml, llvm, opam, ocaml-dune

I built LLVM13 rc4 with OCaml bindings.
After running `ninja install`, I see the bindings is now installed in `$HOME/.opam/4.12.0/lib/ocaml`. However, I run `dune build` and it looks like the system does not realize the bindings is installed.

How do I add the built bindings to OCaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I figured it out. I need to copy them from `lib/ocaml/llvm` to `lib/llvm` and `lib/llvm/static`